# Testing React Async with Jest and create-react-app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, create-react-app

I can't seem to figure this one out. I'm using create-react-app and it's built in test runner Jest. For all synchronous code it seems to work really well, but when mocking promises I can't seem to get it to work.

A react component has a form that I'm able to simulate a submit.

React component code snippets.

```
//Top of the page
import {auth} from '../../lib/API_V2'
// ... //

// Handle submit runs when the form is submitted
handleSubmit = (event) => {
  console.log('submit')
  event.preventDefault()
  this.setState(prevState => ({
    ...prevState,
    loading: true
  }))
  console.log('stateSet')
  auth(this.state.userName, this.state.password)
    .then(results => {
      // NEVER RUNS
      console.log('then')
      // stuff omitted
      this.setState(prevState => ({
        ...prevState,
        loading: false
      }))
      this.props.afterAuth()
    })
  .catch(() => {
    // also never runs
    // omitted
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      ...prevState,
      loading: false
    }))
    this.props.afterAuth()
  })
}
```

Test code

```
jest.mock('../../lib/API_V2')
it.only(`should mock a login`, () => {
  const myMock = jest.fn()
  const authComp = mount(<AuthComponent afterAuth={myMock}/>)

  authComp.find('.userName').simulate('change', {target: {value: 'userName'}})
  authComp.find('.password').simulate('change', {target: {value: 'password'}})
  expect(authComp.state().userName).toEqual('userName')
  expect(authComp.state().password).toEqual('password')
  authComp.find('[type="submit"]').get(0).click()
  expect(myMock.mock.calls.length).toBe(1) // FAILS
})
```

The API lib returns a promise. Instead of using that I have a `__mocks__/API_V2.js` next to it. That looks like this

```
function auth (lastname, accountNumber) {
  console.log('yay!?')
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    resolve({
      accountNumber,
      lastName: lastname
    })
  })
}
```

My mock test code never seems to be run. If I log the mock function I get `function auth() {return mockConstructor.apply(this,arguments);}`

I've tried to follow the instructions https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/tutorial-async.html but it seems as though my mock methods aren't being called. And neither are the actual methods. Instead my call to `auth()` returns undefined.

Anyone have any ideas?

-- Supplementary Information --

```
src
  Components
    AuthComponent
      AuthComponent.js
      AuthComponent.test.js
      index.js
  Lib
    API_V2
      API_V2.js
      index.js
      __mocks__
        API_V2.js
```

Comment: I ended up manually mocking it instead of using the __mocks__ directory.

jest.mock('../../lib/API_V2, () => {auth: function ...})

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're hitting a bug related to this issue: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/2070

Since you're actually trying to import a file called `API_V2/index.js`, you need to mock `index.js`. However, you're going to have a really bad time doing that, since it'll be a valid mock for *every* index.js file that you try to mock.

The best way to do this at the moment is to rewrite some of your code to use dependency-injection and pass in a mock to whatever needs to use `{ auth }`

Comment: In my experience it just annoyed me with warnings, but same name mocks didn't get "swapped".

Comment: > However, you're going to have a really bad time doing that, since it'll be a valid mock for every index.js file that you try to mock.

I don't think this is correct. If he put it in `Lib/API_V2/__mocks__/index.js` that should work and only mock for `Lib/API_V2/index.js`

Comment: Sorry, just looked at the referenced bug. That's annoying. Maybe just rename the file? ;-)

Answer (score 2):

In the new Promise from your mock, even though you immediately resolve, this resolution does not occur synchronously. Promise callbacks always run as an enqueued **microtask**, so when you simulate a click in your test, the Promise callback in your mock has not yet run (and so `myMock` has not been called yet, either). This is why your expectation fails.

One (somewhat hacky) way you could work around this issue would be with a setTimeout. setTimeout will enqueue a **task**, and tasks always run after microtasks.
Jest supports async tests via returning Promises from `it` callbacks, so you might write:

```
jest.mock('../../lib/API_V2')
it.only(`should mock a login`, () => new Promise(resolve => {
  const myMock = jest.fn()
  const authComp = mount(<AuthComponent afterAuth={myMock}/>)

  authComp.find('.userName').simulate('change', {target: {value: 'userName'}})
  authComp.find('.password').simulate('change', {target: {value: 'password'}})
  expect(authComp.state().userName).toEqual('userName')
  expect(authComp.state().password).toEqual('password')
  authComp.find('[type="submit"]').get(0).click()
  setTimeout(() => {
    expect(myMock.mock.calls.length).toBe(1)
    resolve() // Tell jest this test is done running
  }, 0);
}))
```

There is a good explanation of how tasks and microtasks work here: https://jakearchibald.com/2015/tasks-microtasks-queues-and-schedules/